# incorrect binding supplied in sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to create a database from a cif file, and getting an odd error:

```
import sqlite3 as sq

sqlfile = "mats.db"
tabnm = "elems"
id_col = "Properties"
val_col = "Value"

conn = sq.connect(sqlfile)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Trial
          (Properties text, Name text, Phase text, AbM text, AbB text, Cpre text)''')
lists = []
filename = "/var/tmp/1101142.cif"

fullparams=["_journal_coden_ASTM" , "_journal_issue", "_journal_name_full"
,"_journal_page_first","_journal_page_last","_journal_paper_doi"
,"_journal_volume","_journal_year","_chemical_formula_sum"
,"_chemical_formula_weight","_space_group_IT_number","_symmetry_cell_setting"
,"_symmetry_space_group_name_Hall","_symmetry_space_group_name_H-M ","_atom_sites_solution_primary"
,"_atom_sites_solution_secondary ","_audit_creation_method","_cell_angle_alpha"
,"_cell_angle_beta","_cell_angle_gamma","_cell_formula_units_Z"
,"_cell_length_a","_cell_length_b","_cell_length_c"
,"_cell_measurement_reflns_used","_cell_measurement_temperature","_cell_measurement_theta_max"
,"_cell_measurement_theta_min","_cell_volume"]

with open(filename, "r") as cif:
  for line in cif:
    for j in range(6):
      if line.startswith(fullparams[j]):
        # print(line)
        lists.append(line.split()[-1])

print(lists)

c.executemany("INSERT INTO Trial VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",lists)
conn.commit()
```

While I have made sure the number is equal, I am still getting error:

```
python3 parse_cif.py
['CMATEX', '7', "Materials'", '1745', '1752', '10.1021/cm0513738']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_cif.py", line 36, in <module>
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO Trial VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",lists)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 1 supplied.
```

I have no idea how it is counting supplied value 1. I have seen similar question already asked as:[Python 3 SQLite3 - Incorrect number of bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945910/python-3-sqlite3-incorrect-number-of-bindings), [sqlite3 - Incorrect number of bindings supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307064/sqlite3-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied) but cant solve my problem.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executemany()` executes the same statement multiple. So it does not expect a list of paramters, but a list containing multiple parameter lists, one for each execution.

In this case `'CMATEX'` looks like a list containing six characters, so it executes just fine. But the next list, `'7'`, contains only a single value; this is the error you get.

To insert a single row, use `execute()` instead.